# How to sort three dimenisonal array based on the specific index?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Even After lots of search on google I am not able to understand that how I can sort the associative array of 3 dimensional.

Actually, I want to sort each user's alert's jobs according to the posted date of job.

Following is the code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `bf_alert_stack` WHERE `type` = 'immediately'  order by created desc";


$q   = db_query($sql);

$user_alerts = array();

  while ($row  = db_fetch_array($q)) 
{   
   $user_alerts [$row['uid']]    [$row['alert_id']]  [$row['nid']] = $row['nid'];
}
```

Here in $user_alerts array, $row['nid'] contains jobs of particular user's alert.

when user gets email alert at that time it should show the job in sorted order according to date.

Following is the sample data from $user_alerts array

```
Array
(
    [144320] => Array
        (
            [3568728] => Array
                (
                    [30832] => 30832
                )

            [3568884] => Array
                (
                    [30837] => 30837
                    [30827] => 30827
                    [30828] => 30828
                    [30830] => 30830
                    [30831] => 30831
                    [30832] => 30832
                    [30838] => 30838
                    [30839] => 30839
                    [30826] => 30826
                    [30806] => 30806
                    [30808] => 30808
                    [30807] => 30807
                    [30698] => 30698
                    [30697] => 30697
                    [30601] => 30601
                )

        )

    [144330] => Array
        (
            [3568731] => Array
                (
                    [30827] => 30827
                    [30839] => 30839
                    [30838] => 30838
                    [30837] => 30837
                    [30832] => 30832
                    [30831] => 30831
                    [30830] => 30830
                    [30828] => 30828
                    [30826] => 30826
                    [30806] => 30806
                    [30808] => 30808
                    [30807] => 30807
                    [30698] => 30698
                    [30697] => 30697
                    [30601] => 30601
                )

        )

    [144218] => Array
        (
            [3568753] => Array
                (
                    [30808] => 30808
                )

        )

    [144216] => Array
        (
            [3568732] => Array
                (
                    [30808] => 30808
                )

        )

)
```

I want to sort this above user_alerts array based on row['nid'] but row['nid']'s details are in database table.all nid should be rearranged according to created date of nid which is present in table.

Comment: what should I consider as date here ... ?

Comment: Actually Node no. is used to retrieve date from table

Comment: so I have to use `$row['nid']` for sorting

Comment: You app background seems irrelevant here, and they're taking up a lots of space (and you didn't demonstrate your expected output). Suggest to re-format your question as "I have an multidimensional array that looks like this...and I want to sort it so it would look like this...".

Comment: @dreamCoder: yes $row['nid'] should be sorted according to nid's created date which is present in database

Comment: @Akki thats what I am asking .. I cannot find created date in your array ... please tell me your desired output . in array format

Comment: Since you do `order by created desc`in your SQL, elements get added to the array in that order – it should already be sorted by created. Because you don't show the created date we cannot know in which way your sample is sorted incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Little confusing this but perhaps by chance this will work.. ?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `bf_alert_stack` WHERE `type` = 'immediately' ORDER BY `created` DESC, `uid` ASC, `alert_id` DESC, `nid` DESC";
```